# Call "expr" in xCode console automatically?

Tags: xcode, console, automation, command, lldb

I need to perform a command in console:

```
expr @import UIKit
```

This command makes `lldb` more similar to `gdb`. It is better than to add an implicit type conversion to each `CGPoint` or `CGRect` value but I need to perform this after each relaunch. How to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this in Xcode right now is to put a breakpoint on main, set it to auto-continue, and then add your expression to the commands.  There are situations where you need to debug code before you hit main (e.g. library startup code) but that's pretty infrequent...

Then if you want all your projects to inherit this breakpoint, open the breakpoints navigator, right-click on the breakpoint and choose Move To->User.  Then it will be present in all your projects.

Comment: I don't like this way because I work with breakpoints a lot and may delete this breakpoint by chance. It is possible but not very handy. Maybe are there are any ways via `NSLog` or target/scheme?